# Determine whether each of following is cyclic: $\Bbb Z_7, \Bbb Z_9, \Bbb Z_{10}, \Bbb Z_9^{\times}, \Bbb Z_{20}^{\times}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

> Determine whether each of the following is cyclic:
>
> $$\Bbb Z_7, \Bbb Z_9, \Bbb Z_{10}, \Bbb Z_9^{\times}, \Bbb Z_{20}^{\times}.$$
>
> ---

**Theorems:**

1) If $p$ and $q$ are primes then evry proper subgroup of order $p*q$ is cyclic.

2) $p\in  \Bbb Z^{>0}$, $p$ is prime every and a group of order $p$ is cyclic and isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_p$.

---

**Attempt:**

$\Bbb Z_7$ is cyclic by theorem 2. Not sure what generates it. $\Bbb Z_9^{\times}$ theorem 1 applies.

$ \Bbb Z_{20}$ and $ \Bbb Z_{20}^{\times}$ guessing no. Missing a theorem??

*Should I use brute force and check the order of every element of $\Bbb Z_{20}$ because I will?*

Comment: What's the difference between $Z_{20}$ and $z_{20}$? Is there one or is this just a typo?

Comment: one is the units of $Z_{20}$. it suppose to be $Z_{20}^{\times}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every $ℤ_n$ is cyclic. For $ℤ_n^×$, there is a theorem that its elements are precisely elements of $ℤ_n$ coprime with $n$, so $\lvertℤ_n\rvert = φ(n)$. You can just write down the elements and observe the group structure.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbf Z_9^\times$ has order $\varphi(9)=6$ and it's abelian. There are only two isomorphism classes of groups of order $6$:

- a non-abelian group of order $6$ is isomorphic to the symmetric group $S_3$;
- an abelian group of order $6$ is isomorphic to the cyclic group $\mathbf Z/6\mathbf Z$.

For  $\mathbf Z_{20}^\times$, as by the *Chinese remainder theorem*, $\;\mathbf Z /20\mathbf Z\simeq(\mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z)\times(\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z)$, we have
$$(\mathbf Z /20\mathbf Z)^\times\simeq(\mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z)^\times\times(\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z)^\times\simeq\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z\times \mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z,$$
which is *not* cyclic, as all its elements have order $\le 4$.